# simple method in User model - trying to call it in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-models, rails-console

Ok, simplistic question.

There's this method in User model:

```
def name_email
   "#{first_name} #{last_name} - #{email}"
 end
```

All right, by the virtue of the fact that it doesn't have self attached to the method, one can deduct that it's an instance method, right?

So, I crack open the console, and try to initialize it like this:

```
 LaLaLa = User.new
```

Then I try to set this method by setting the first name first like this:

```
Jesse = LaLaLa.first_name
```

which gets me this:

```
=> nil
```

Then I try to set the last name:

```
Smith = LaLaLa.last_name
```

which gets me this again:

```
=> nil
```

Then I try to set email:

```
FakeEmail = LaLaLa.email
```

which gets me this:

```
=> ""
```

Then I try to have the first name, last name and email by calling the method like this:

```
LaLaLa.name_email
```

which gets me this:

```
=> "  - "
```

Which brings me to my question, why is this not working in the console? And what am I doing wrong here?

I mean, I set the first name, last name, and email as you can see.

Why doesn't the method display the results?

Let me know if this question could be phrased better.

Comment: @Santosh, just ran `reload!` right now, and then ran `LaLaLa.name_email` method again, and it still shows the same results in console

Comment: You are clearly struggling with the ruby basics: just an half hour on http://tryruby.org will let you learn these by example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be setting the name like this

```
LaLaLa.first_name = 'Jesse'
LaLaLa.last_name = 'Smith'
LaLaLa.email = 'FakeEmail'
```

Comment: Accepted because it was the first answer. Thank you by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen what you have written?

You are getting nil because you are giving a nil value to an unset variable...

Jesse is an unset variable, and you are giving it the value at LaLaLa.first_name...

You should do

```
LaLaLa.first_name = "Jesse"
```

etc...

and at the end

```
LaLaLa.save
```

Note: In ruby it's common practice to give instance variables names with the first letter non capital. Capital first letters mean classes... So, to be correct, do :

```
lalala=User.new
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and adding a bit of extra explanations. Much appreciated.